# empirical orthogonal function with NCtoolkit

Tags: python, python-3.x, netcdf4

I am working with SST data obtained from https://podaac.jpl.nasa.gov/dataset/MUR-JPL-L4-GLOB-v4.1. I am looking at visualizing non-seasonal trends, such as those posed ENSO.

right now I want to conduct an EOF analysis to decompose the dataset into signals.

I have been using Robert Wilson's nctoolkit for a lot of my previous analysis, and would like to continue using it to conduct the EOF. Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to conduct the EOF using the functions available in this kit. Is it possible to conduct an EOI with this kit? Hwat would the steps involved be?
https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/temporals.html?highlight=average#temporal-statistics

I am grateful to anyone that can shed some light on this.
TY
J.Lasu

Comment: If you are interested in this being added as an explicit nctoolkit method, raise an issue here: https://github.com/pmlmodelling/nctoolkit/issues. I can look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, right now, is no. At least not with the built in methods. However, nctoolkit uses CDO under-the-hood, so you can use CDO's EOF methods with the `cdo_command` method.

For example, this CDO call is given in their user guide:

```
cdo eof,40 infile outfile1 outfile2
```

You could do this in nctoolkit as follows:

```
ds.cdo_command("eof,40")
```

CDO methods given from p. 158 onwards in the user guide: https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/cdo.pdf